# API with nested JSON parse into CSV file in ADF

Tags: json, azure, csv, azure-data-factory, flatten

I get a generated Json file from the Log Analytics API into ADF, and I want to convert it to CSV file. My Json file has this structure:

```
{
    "tables": [
        {
            "name": "PrimaryResult",
            "columns": [
                {
                    "name": "PipelineName",
                    "type": "string"
                },
                {
                    "name": "Status",
                    "type": "string"
                },
                {
                    "name": "TimeGenerated",
                    "type": "datetime"
                },
                {
                    "name": "_ResourceId",
                    "type": "string"
                },
                {
                    "name": "Type",
                    "type": "string"
                }
            ],
            "rows": [
                [
                    "Get_Tables",
                    "Succeeded",
                    "2023-09-04T08:15:48.77315Z",
                    "/subscriptions/144612ca-37be-4643-9c80-5706a350bdb2/resourcegroups"
                ],
                [
                    "LogAnaytics",
                    "Succeeded",
                    "2023-09-04T08:15:55.073672Z",
                    "/subscriptions/providers/microsoft.datafactory/factories",
                    "ADFPipelineRun"
                ]
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

I tried to flaten, firstly table than columns than rows like this:[image] but it did not work. I want to get a result in csv like this:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To achieve your requirement, follow below steps, I took your sample Json and transformed it:

- First import the projection properly in source.
  [image]
  data preview:
  [image]

**For Columns**

- First flatten the columns using flatten activity.
  [image]
  data preview:
  [image]
- Add a Surrogate column
  [image]
  data preview:
  [image]
- Then using pivot transformation convert columns into row.
  [image]
  No need to set group by
  [image]
  data preview:
  [image]

**For Rows**

- Then flatten the rows.
  [image]
  data preview:
  [image]
- Using derived column transformation unfold nested array.
  [image]
  data preview:
  [image]
- Then use select transformation and delete array column.
  [image]
  data preview:
  [image]

**Now using Union transformation combine the rows and columns**

[image]

data preview:
[image]

**Now, using sink transformation load data into CSV**

- Sink settings
  Add CSV dataset in Sink and follow below settings.
  [image]

**Output:**
[image]