# Json merged file parsed in csv file in ADF Copy data activity

Tags: json, azure, csv, mapping, azure-data-factory

I am retrieve some API response which are saved in separated files through for each loop. Then I am using a copy data activity where all the JSON files created in for each loop, I am merging in one single JSON file. Now what I am concern is that, I want to save all the rows array items, as a table. Till now I have reached to extract the  first row item array, for each API generated json, but I need to take all item arrays of the merged file.

The merged  API JSON file looks like this:

```
[{"tables":[{"name":"PrimaryResult","columns":[{"name":"PipelineName","type":"string"},{"name":"Status","type":"string"},{"name":"TimeGenerated","type":"datetime"},{"name":"_ResourceId","type":"string"},{"name":"Type","type":"string"}],"rows":[]}]}
,{"tables":[{"name":"PrimaryResult","columns":[{"name":"PipelineName","type":"string"},{"name":"Status","type":"string"},{"name":"TimeGenerated","type":"datetime"},{"name":"_ResourceId","type":"string"},{"name":"Type","type":"string"}],"rows":[]}]}
,{"tables":[{"name":"PrimaryResult","columns":[{"name":"PipelineName","type":"string"},{"name":"Status","type":"string"},{"name":"TimeGenerated","type":"datetime"},{"name":"_ResourceId","type":"string"},{"name":"Type","type":"string"}],"rows":[["EC2PF_Part3_TopAnlagen","Succeeded","2023-08-15T11:32:29.120704Z","/providers/microsoft.datafactory/factories/dfactory","ADFPipelineRun"],["CreateECountAnlagenExtended","Succeeded","2023-08-15T11:35:31.284712Z","/providers/microsoft.datafactory/factories/dfactory","ADFPipelineRun"],["CreateFlxresEinheiten","Succeeded","2023-08-15T11:37:17.255339Z","/providers/microsoft.datafactory/factories/dfactory","ADFPipelineRun"],["CreateECountFlxresExtended","Succeeded","2023-08-15T11:39:18.948178Z","/providers/microsoft.datafactory/factories/dfactory","ADFPipelineRun"],["curateGINIUSvsECount","Succeeded","2023-08-15T11:44:02.991948Z","/providers/microsoft.datafactory/factories/dfactory","ADFPipelineRun"],["curateGINIUSvsSoptimEKM","Succeeded","2023-08-15T11:48:48.04538Z","/providers/microsoft.datafactory/factories/dfactory","ADFPipelineRun"],["CurateSoptimEKMEEGAnlagen","Succeeded","2023-08-15T11:56:02.22626Z","/providers/microsoft.datafactory/factories/dfactory","ADFPipelineRun"],["AllDataflows","Succeeded","2023-08-15T11:56:05.46919Z","/providers/microsoft.datafactory/factories/dfactory","ADFPipelineRun"]]}]}
,{"tables":[{"name":"PrimaryResult","columns":[{"name":"PipelineName","type":"string"},{"name":"Status","type":"string"},{"name":"TimeGenerated","type":"datetime"},{"name":"_ResourceId","type":"string"},{"name":"Type","type":"string"}],"rows":[["csvToParquet","Succeeded","2023-09-07T06:33:27.15381Z","/providers/microsoft.datafactory/factories/dfactory","ADFPipelineRun"],["csvToParquet","Succeeded","2023-09-07T06:39:14.272804Z","/providers/microsoft.datafactory/factories/dfactory","ADFPipelineRun"],["csvToParquet","Succeeded","2023-09-07T11:41:41.178384Z","/providers/microsoft.datafactory/factories/dfactory","ADFPipelineRun"],["LogAnalyticsFlow","Succeeded","2023-09-07T13:02:09.790652Z","/providers/microsoft.datafactory/factories/dfactory","ADFPipelineRun"],["LogAnalyticsFlow","Succeeded","2023-09-07T13:41:50.799101Z","/providers/microsoft.datafactory/factories/dfactory","ADFPipelineRun"],["LogAnalyticsFlow","Succeeded","2023-09-07T14:02:05.363832Z","/providers/microsoft.datafactory/factories/dfactory","ADFPipelineRun"],["LogAnalyticsFlow","Succeeded","2023-09-07T14:08:32.283883Z","/providers/microsoft.datafactory/factories/dfactory","ADFPipelineRun"],["LogAnalyticsFlow","Succeeded","2023-09-07T14:14:22.496675Z","/providers/microsoft.datafactory/factories/dfactory","ADFPipelineRun"],["LogAnalyticsFlow","Succeeded","2023-09-07T14:33:41.980251Z","/providers/microsoft.datafactory/factories/dfactory","ADFPipelineRun"]]}]}
,{"tables":[{"name":"PrimaryResult","columns":[{"name":"PipelineName","type":"string"},{"name":"Status","type":"string"},{"name":"TimeGenerated","type":"datetime"},{"name":"_ResourceId","type":"string"},{"name":"Type","type":"string"}],"rows":[]}]}
,{"tables":[{"name":"PrimaryResult","columns":[{"name":"PipelineName","type":"string"},{"name":"Status","type":"string"},{"name":"TimeGenerated","type":"datetime"},{"name":"_ResourceId","type":"string"},{"name":"Type","type":"string"}],"rows":[]}]}
,{"tables":[{"name":"PrimaryResult","columns":[{"name":"PipelineName","type":"string"},{"name":"Status","type":"string"},{"name":"TimeGenerated","type":"datetime"},{"name":"_ResourceId","type":"string"},{"name":"Type","type":"string"}],"rows":[["LogAnaytics","Succeeded","2023-09-08T07:21:50.936371Z","/providers/microsoft.datafactory/factories/dfactory","ADFPipelineRun"],["LogAnaytics","Succeeded","2023-09-08T08:25:32.740153Z","/providers/microsoft.datafactory/factories/dfactory","ADFPipelineRun"],["LogAnaytics","Succeeded","2023-09-08T08:40:32.732672Z","/providers/microsoft.datafactory/factories/dfactory","ADFPipelineRun"],["LogAnaytics","Succeeded","2023-09-08T09:21:48.903464Z","/providers/microsoft.datafactory/factories/dfactory","ADFPipelineRun"],["LogAnaytics","Succeeded","2023-09-08T09:55:13.416172Z","/providers/microsoft.datafactory/factories/dfactory","ADFPipelineRun"],["LogAnaytics","Succeeded","2023-09-08T10:05:28.500085Z","/providers/microsoft.datafactory/factories/dfactory","ADFPipelineRun"],["LogAnaytics","Succeeded","2023-09-08T11:10:03.799294Z","/providers/microsoft.datafactory/factories/dfactory","ADFPipelineRun"],["LogAnaytics","Succeeded","2023-09-08T11:48:04.072832Z","/providers/microsoft.datafactory/factories/dfactory","ADFPipelineRun"],["LogAnaytics","Succeeded","2023-09-08T12:15:33.620322Z","/providers/microsoft.datafactory/factories/dfactory","ADFPipelineRun"],["LogAnaytics","Succeeded","2023-09-08T12:38:59.615093Z","/providers/microsoft.datafactory/factories/dfactory","ADFPipelineRun"],["LogAnaytics","Succeeded","2023-09-08T13:59:41.945903Z","/providers/microsoft.datafactory/factories/dfactory","ADFPipelineRun"]]}]}
,{"tables":[{"name":"PrimaryResult","columns":[{"name":"PipelineName","type":"string"},{"name":"Status","type":"string"},{"name":"TimeGenerated","type":"datetime"},{"name":"_ResourceId","type":"string"},{"name":"Type","type":"string"}],"rows":[["GetECount_FLEXR_Tables","Succeeded","2023-08-17T06:33:48.202237Z","/providers/microsoft.datafactory/factories/dfactory","ADFPipelineRun"],["GetECount_EEE_Tables","Succeeded","2023-08-17T06:36:13.860009Z","/providers/microsoft.datafactory/factories/dfactory","ADFPipelineRun"],["GetECount_FlexRes2Umspannwerk","Succeeded","2023-08-17T06:36:36.949946Z","/providers/microsoft.datafactory/factories/dfactory","ADFPipelineRun"],["Get_ECAnlagen2Umspannwerk","Succeeded","2023-08-17T06:37:00.725488Z","/providers/microsoft.datafactory/factories/dfactory","ADFPipelineRun"],["GetECount_Lieferant_Tables","Succeeded","2023-08-17T06:38:15.774104Z","/providers/microsoft.datafactory/factories/dfactory","ADFPipelineRun"],["GetECount_ZPT_Tables2","Succeeded","2023-08-17T06:39:34.637317Z","/providers/microsoft.datafactory/factories/dfactory","ADFPipelineRun"],["GetECount_ZPT_Tables","Succeeded","2023-08-17T06:50:25.189962Z","/providers/microsoft.datafactory/factories/dfactory","ADFPipelineRun"],["GetECount_Regelzone","Succeeded","2023-08-17T06:54:04.633444Z","/providers/microsoft.datafactory/factories/dfactory","ADFPipelineRun"],["GetECount_SYS_Tables","Succeeded","2023-08-17T07:03:15.363786Z","/providers/microsoft.datafactory/factories/dfactory","ADFPipelineRun"],["GetECOUNT_NA_Tables","Succeeded","2023-08-17T07:07:53.032784Z","/providers/microsoft.datafactory/factories/dfactory","ADFPipelineRun"],["ingECQueryFlexres","Succeeded","2023-08-17T07:08:08.629406Z","/providers/microsoft.datafactory/factories/dfactory","ADFPipelineRun"],["GetECount_Gruppen_Tables","Succeeded","2023-08-17T07:08:34.641916Z","/providers/microsoft.datafactory/factories/dfactory","ADFPipelineRun"],["IngestBIZAGI","Succeeded","2023-08-17T07:10:06.841188Z","/providers/microsoft.datafactory/factories/dfactory","ADFPipelineRun"],["CreateECountAnlagenExtended","Succeeded","2023-08-17T07:17:26.303981Z","/providers/microsoft.datafactory/factories/dfactory","ADFPipelineRun"],["CreateFlxresEinheiten","Succeeded","2023-08-17T07:19:27.731394Z","/providers/microsoft.datafactory/factories/dfactory","ADFPipelineRun"],["CreateECountFlxresExtended","Succeeded","2023-08-17T07:21:41.963439Z","/providers/microsoft.datafactory/factories/dfactory","ADFPipelineRun"],["curateGINIUSvsECount","Succeeded","2023-08-17T07:27:04.955413Z","/providers/microsoft.datafactory/factories/dfactory","ADFPipelineRun"],["curateGINIUSvsSoptimEKM","Succeeded","2023-08-17T07:32:25.389198Z","/providers/microsoft.datafactory/factories/dfactory","ADFPipelineRun"],["CurateSoptimEKMEEGAnlagen","Succeeded","2023-08-17T07:40:31.250797Z","/providers/microsoft.datafactory/factories/dfactory","ADFPipelineRun"],["CurateFlexibleRessources","Succeeded","2023-08-17T07:42:31.64909Z","/providers/microsoft.datafactory/factories/dfactory","ADFPipelineRun"],["curateBIZAGIunionBestand","Succeeded","2023-08-17T07:43:05.667999Z","/providers/microsoft.datafactory/factories/dfactory","ADFPipelineRun"],["probECQueryFlexres","Succeeded","2023-08-17T07:43:24.075925Z","/providers/microsoft.datafactory/factories/dfactory","ADFPipelineRun"],["curateBIZAGIvsExcelAnlage","Succeeded","2023-08-17T07:46:11.773962Z","/providers/microsoft.datafactory/factories/dfactory","ADFPipelineRun"],["createBizagiAnlage","Succeeded","2023-08-17T07:46:28.69844Z","/providers/microsoft.datafactory/factories/dfactory","ADFPipelineRun"],["ingRawBestandPhotovoltaikExcel","Succeeded","2023-08-17T07:48:33.453314Z","/providers/microsoft.datafactory/factories/dfactory","ADFPipelineRun"],["curBizagiBestandEKM","Succeeded","2023-08-17T07:48:53.782033Z","/providers/microsoft.datafactory/factories/dfactory","ADFPipelineRun"],["CurateEinspeiseanlagenExcel","Succeeded","2023-08-17T07:49:28.50735Z","/providers/microsoft.datafactory/factories/dfactory","ADFPipelineRun"],["DailyJob","Succeeded","2023-08-17T07:49:30.331512Z","/providers/microsoft.datafactory/factories/dfactory","ADFPipelineRun"]]}]}
,{"tables":[{"name":"PrimaryResult","columns":[{"name":"PipelineName","type":"string"},{"name":"Status","type":"string"},{"name":"TimeGenerated","type":"datetime"},{"name":"_ResourceId","type":"string"},{"name":"Type","type":"string"}],"rows":[["LogAnalyticsFlow","Succeeded","2023-09-06T11:54:48.911287Z","/providers/microsoft.datafactory/factories/dfactory","ADFPipelineRun"],["LogAnalyticsFlow","Succeeded","2023-09-06T11:54:57.034405Z","/providers/microsoft.datafactory/factories/dfactory","ADFPipelineRun"],["LogAnalyticsFlow","Succeeded","2023-09-06T13:46:10.397883Z","/providers/microsoft.datafactory/factories/dfactory","ADFPipelineRun"]]}]}
,{"tables":[{"name":"PrimaryResult","columns":[{"name":"PipelineName","type":"string"},{"name":"Status","type":"string"},{"name":"TimeGenerated","type":"datetime"},{"name":"_ResourceId","type":"string"},{"name":"Type","type":"string"}],"rows":[]}]}
,{"tables":[{"name":"PrimaryResult","columns":[{"name":"PipelineName","type":"string"},{"name":"Status","type":"string"},{"name":"TimeGenerated","type":"datetime"},{"name":"_ResourceId","type":"string"},{"name":"Type","type":"string"}],"rows":[["pipeline2","Succeeded","2023-09-05T07:30:48.655564Z","/providers/microsoft.datafactory/factories/dfactory","ADFPipelineRun"],["pipeline2","Succeeded","2023-09-05T08:09:49.226269Z","/providers/microsoft.datafactory/factories/dfactory","ADFPipelineRun"],["pipeline2","Succeeded","2023-09-05T08:45:34.140599Z","/providers/microsoft.datafactory/factories/dfactory","ADFPipelineRun"],["LogAnaytics","Succeeded","2023-09-05T09:43:07.986238Z","/providers/microsoft.datafactory/factories/dfactory","ADFPipelineRun"],["LogAnaytics","Succeeded","2023-09-05T09:54:12.673131Z","/providers/microsoft.datafactory/factories/dfactory","ADFPipelineRun"],["LogAnaytics","Succeeded","2023-09-05T10:17:50.844621Z","/providers/microsoft.datafactory/factories/dfactory","ADFPipelineRun"],["LogAnaytics","Succeeded","2023-09-05T11:59:30.793858Z","/providers/microsoft.datafactory/factories/dfactory","ADFPipelineRun"]]}]}
,{"tables":[{"name":"PrimaryResult","columns":[{"name":"PipelineName","type":"string"},{"name":"Status","type":"string"},{"name":"TimeGenerated","type":"datetime"},{"name":"_ResourceId","type":"string"},{"name":"Type","type":"string"}],"rows":[]}]}
,{"tables":[{"name":"PrimaryResult","columns":[{"name":"PipelineName","type":"string"},{"name":"Status","type":"string"},{"name":"TimeGenerated","type":"datetime"},{"name":"_ResourceId","type":"string"},{"name":"Type","type":"string"}],"rows":[]}]}
,{"tables":[{"name":"PrimaryResult","columns":[{"name":"PipelineName","type":"string"},{"name":"Status","type":"string"},{"name":"TimeGenerated","type":"datetime"},{"name":"_ResourceId","type":"string"},{"name":"Type","type":"string"}],"rows":[]}]}
,{"tables":[{"name":"PrimaryResult","columns":[{"name":"PipelineName","type":"string"},{"name":"Status","type":"string"},{"name":"TimeGenerated","type":"datetime"},{"name":"_ResourceId","type":"string"},{"name":"Type","type":"string"}],"rows":[["GetECount_FLEXR_Tables","Succeeded","2023-09-04T08:00:20.658823Z","/providers/microsoft.datafactory/factories/dfactory","ADFPipelineRun"],["GetECount_EEE_Tables","Succeeded","2023-09-04T08:02:45.282715Z","/providers/microsoft.datafactory/factories/dfactory","ADFPipelineRun"],["GetECount_FlexRes2Umspannwerk","Succeeded","2023-09-04T08:03:09.521574Z","/providers/microsoft.datafactory/factories/dfactory","ADFPipelineRun"],["Get_ECAnlagen2Umspannwerk","Succeeded","2023-09-04T08:03:33.191387Z","/providers/microsoft.datafactory/factories/dfactory","ADFPipelineRun"],["GetECount_Lieferant_Tables","Succeeded","2023-09-04T08:04:47.494212Z","/providers/microsoft.datafactory/factories/dfactory","ADFPipelineRun"],["GetECount_ZPT_Tables2","Succeeded","2023-09-04T08:06:08.732235Z","/providers/microsoft.datafactory/factories/dfactory","ADFPipelineRun"],["GetECount_ZPT_Tables","Succeeded","2023-09-04T08:15:48.77315Z","/providers/microsoft.datafactory/factories/dfactory","ADFPipelineRun"],["LogAnaytics","Succeeded","2023-09-04T08:15:55.073672Z","/providers/microsoft.datafactory/factories/dfactory","ADFPipelineRun"],["GetECount_Regelzone","Succeeded","2023-09-04T08:19:27.165214Z","/providers/microsoft.datafactory/factories/dfactory","ADFPipelineRun"],["GetECount_SYS_Tables","Succeeded","2023-09-04T08:28:29.922937Z","/providers/microsoft.datafactory/factories/dfactory","ADFPipelineRun"],["GetECOUNT_NA_Tables","Succeeded","2023-09-04T08:33:08.995352Z","/providers/microsoft.datafactory/factories/dfactory","ADFPipelineRun"],["ingECQueryFlexres","Succeeded","2023-09-04T08:33:24.751274Z","/providers/microsoft.datafactory/factories/dfactory","ADFPipelineRun"],["GetECount_Gruppen_Tables","Succeeded","2023-09-04T08:33:50.765466Z","/providers/microsoft.datafactory/factories/dfactory","ADFPipelineRun"],["IngestBIZAGI","Succeeded","2023-09-04T08:35:05.045513Z","/providers/microsoft.datafactory/factories/dfactory","ADFPipelineRun"],["LogAnaytics","Succeeded","2023-09-04T08:37:03.591298Z","/providers/microsoft.datafactory/factories/dfactory","ADFPipelineRun"],["CreateECountAnlagenExtended","Succeeded","2023-09-04T08:41:56.090302Z","/providers/microsoft.datafactory/factories/dfactory","ADFPipelineRun"],["CreateFlxresEinheiten","Succeeded","2023-09-04T08:43:49.781644Z","/providers/microsoft.datafactory/factories/dfactory","ADFPipelineRun"],["CreateECountFlxresExtended","Succeeded","2023-09-04T08:45:58.749538Z","/providers/microsoft.datafactory/factories/dfactory","ADFPipelineRun"],["curateGINIUSvsECount","Succeeded","2023-09-04T08:51:15.870807Z","/providers/microsoft.datafactory/factories/dfactory","ADFPipelineRun"],["curateGINIUSvsSoptimEKM","Succeeded","2023-09-04T08:56:27.391099Z","/providers/microsoft.datafactory/factories/dfactory","ADFPipelineRun"],["CurateSoptimEKMEEGAnlagen","Succeeded","2023-09-04T09:04:18.703808Z","/providers/microsoft.datafactory/factories/dfactory","ADFPipelineRun"],["CurateFlexibleRessources","Succeeded","2023-09-04T09:06:14.962942Z","/providers/microsoft.datafactory/factories/dfactory","ADFPipelineRun"],["curateBIZAGIunionBestand","Succeeded","2023-09-04T09:06:47.728712Z","/providers/microsoft.datafactory/factories/dfactory","ADFPipelineRun"],["probECQueryFlexres","Succeeded","2023-09-04T09:07:00.283812Z","/providers/microsoft.datafactory/factories/dfactory","ADFPipelineRun"],["curateBIZAGIvsExcelAnlage","Succeeded","2023-09-04T09:09:40.825211Z","/providers/microsoft.datafactory/factories/dfactory","ADFPipelineRun"],["createBizagiAnlage","Succeeded","2023-09-04T09:09:54.571941Z","/providers/microsoft.datafactory/factories/dfactory","ADFPipelineRun"],["ingRawBestandPhotovoltaikExcel","Succeeded","2023-09-04T09:13:44.550155Z","/providers/microsoft.datafactory/factories/dfactory","ADFPipelineRun"],["curBizagiBestandEKM","Succeeded","2023-09-04T09:14:03.760771Z","/providers/microsoft.datafactory/factories/dfactory","ADFPipelineRun"],["CurateEinspeiseanlagenExcel","Succeeded","2023-09-04T09:14:35.509703Z","/providers/microsoft.datafactory/factories/dfactory","ADFPipelineRun"],["DailyJob","Succeeded","2023-09-04T09:14:37.30494Z","/providers/microsoft.datafactory/factories/dfactory","ADFPipelineRun"]]}]}
]
```

and the csv file that is created when I use the copy data activity is:

[image]

[image]

```
respwectivly, for each column :
$['tables'][]['rows'][0][0]
$['tables'][]['rows'][0][1]
$['tables'][]['rows'][0][2]
$['tables'][]['rows'][0][3]
$['tables'][*]['rows'][0][4]
```

The result of CSV i am getting is one item of row array for each json file and I want to get all row array items:
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Copy activity won't give the desired CSV file because it won't handle the nested array values.

Instead of copy activity, you can achieve your requirement using ADF Dataflow.

After ForEach, **invoke the Dataflow using dataflow activity** and create a new Dataflow. In the dataflow, give your source **JSON** file.

Similar to copy activity wild card path, in **dataflow also you can give wild card path for your JSON files**.

[image]

Go to **JSON settings** in Source options and select **Array of documents**.

I followed the same approach from this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77038814/18836744) by **@Pratik Lad**. But I have modified it to use it for the multiple JSON source files.

**These are some modifications I have done to the mentioned answer:**

**Data preview after Surrogate key transformation:**

[image]

You can see that as we are dealing multiple files, we got duplicate rows after flattening the columns array. So, I have added a filter activity to get the desired values.

`ColKey<=5`

[image]

Also, to get the rows as columns I have given `column_names` column to  `Pivot key`.

[image]

This will give the result like this.

[image]

But we want only the header for the Union transformation, so I have used another filter transformation after this and given `false()` in it. This will give only the header.

[image]

Now, Use union after this. Give the csv file in sink and you will get the desired result like below.

[image]

**My Dataflow JSON for your reference:**

```
{
    "name": "dataflow3",
    "properties": {
        "type": "MappingDataFlow",
        "typeProperties": {
            "sources": [
                {
                    "dataset": {
                        "referenceName": "source_json_files",
                        "type": "DatasetReference"
                    },
                    "name": "source1"
                }
            ],
            "sinks": [
                {
                    "dataset": {
                        "referenceName": "csv_target",
                        "type": "DatasetReference"
                    },
                    "name": "sink1"
                }
            ],
            "transformations": [
                {
                    "name": "flattenForRows"
                },
                {
                    "name": "flattenforcolumns"
                },
                {
                    "name": "pivot1"
                },
                {
                    "name": "surrogateKey1"
                },
                {
                    "name": "filter1"
                },
                {
                    "name": "derivedColumn1"
                },
                {
                    "name": "select1"
                },
                {
                    "name": "union1"
                },
                {
                    "name": "filter2"
                }
            ],
            "scriptLines": [
                "source(output(",
                "          tables as (columns as (name as string, type as string)[], name as string, rows as string[][])[]",
                "     ),",
                "     allowSchemaDrift: true,",
                "     validateSchema: false,",
                "     ignoreNoFilesFound: false,",
                "     documentForm: 'arrayOfDocuments',",
                "     wildcardPaths:['*.json']) ~> source1",
                "source1 foldDown(unroll(tables.rows, tables.rows),",
                "     mapColumn(",
                "          rows = tables.rows",
                "     ),",
                "     skipDuplicateMapInputs: true,",
                "     skipDuplicateMapOutputs: true) ~> flattenForRows",
                "source1 foldDown(unroll(tables.columns, tables.columns),",
                "     mapColumn(",
                "          column_names = tables.columns.name",
                "     ),",
                "     skipDuplicateMapInputs: true,",
                "     skipDuplicateMapOutputs: true) ~> flattenforcolumns",
                "filter1 pivot(pivotBy(column_names),",
                "     {} = max(column_names),",
                "     columnNaming: '$N$V',",
                "     lateral: false) ~> pivot1",
                "flattenforcolumns keyGenerate(output(ColKey as long),",
                "     startAt: 1L,",
                "     stepValue: 1L) ~> surrogateKey1",
                "surrogateKey1 filter(ColKey<=5) ~> filter1",
                "flattenForRows derive(rc1 = rows[1],",
                "          rc2 = rows[2],",
                "          rc3 = rows[3],",
                "          rc4 = rows[4],",
                "          rc5 = rows[5]) ~> derivedColumn1",
                "derivedColumn1 select(mapColumn(",
                "          rc1,",
                "          rc2,",
                "          rc3,",
                "          rc4,",
                "          rc5",
                "     ),",
                "     skipDuplicateMapInputs: true,",
                "     skipDuplicateMapOutputs: true) ~> select1",
                "filter2, select1 union(byName: false)~> union1",
                "pivot1 filter(false()) ~> filter2",
                "union1 sink(allowSchemaDrift: true,",
                "     validateSchema: false,",
                "     partitionFileNames:['target.csv'],",
                "     umask: 0022,",
                "     preCommands: [],",
                "     postCommands: [],",
                "     skipDuplicateMapInputs: true,",
                "     skipDuplicateMapOutputs: true,",
                "     partitionBy('hash', 1)) ~> sink1"
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, I am still having some problem. On the pipeline I am using copy data activity to merge all JSONs into one JSON file with Copy behavior Merge files, and File pattern : Array of objects. I followed your steps, without wildcard path in source option.Job failed due to reason: at Source 'source1': Malformed records are detected in schema inference. Parse Mode: FAILFAST. It could be because of a wrong selection in document form to parse json file(s). Please try a different 'Document form' (Single document/Document per line/Array of documents) on the json source. Could you please help?

Comment: You need to use dataflow instead of copy activity. Import the projection in the dataflow source and try again.